# How to split string by whitespace or by a dot?

Tags: ruby, regex

For example as input I may receive `"qwer.qwer"` or `"qwer qwer"`. In both cases I need to split this string so I get result:

```
["qwer", "qwer"]
```

Can I use regex as a spliter, and what this regex must look like?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
'qwer.qwer'.split(/\s|\./)
# => ["qwer", "qwer"]
'qwer qwer'.split(/\s|\./)
# => ["qwer", "qwer"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use character class `[.\s]`:

```
"qwer.qwer".split(/[.\s]/) # => ["qwer", "qwer"]
"qwer qwer".split(/[.\s]/) # => ["qwer", "qwer"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Do as below using `String#scan` instead of `Strin#split`:

```
"qwer.qwer".scan(/\w+/)
# => ["qwer", "qwer"]
"qwer qwer".scan(/\w+/)
# => ["qwer", "qwer"]
```

Comment: The first version was technically closer to what the poster wanted. Maybe you should feature both.

Comment: @nneonneo Don't down-vote for such stupid stuffs. It is good to use `String#scan` instead of `splitting`. OP might not be thinking about there is a `#scan` method.

Comment: `'qwer;qwer'.scan(/\w+/) #=> ["qwer", "qwer"]`

Comment: @nneonneo Sorry then..!! Some people in SO are doing spam by giving such down votes...without seeing what answerers are posting actually...

Comment: @MarekLipka I don't get you.. what do you mean ? :)

Comment: Thank you Babai!! `scan` is simple and splits not only by ' ' or ','. `"qwer qwer".scan(/\w+/)
 => ["qwer", "qwer"] 
"qwer.qwer".scan(/\w+/)
 => ["qwer", "qwer"] 
"qwer,qwer".scan(/\w+/)
 => ["qwer", "qwer"] 
"qwer*qwer".scan(/\w+/)
 => ["qwer", "qwer"] 
"qwer'qwer".scan(/\w+/)
 => ["qwer", "qwer"] `

Comment: @MarekLipka why?? OP wanted to take out the `"qwer"` and `"qwer"`. And scan is doing the same... what's the problem?

Comment: The question is "How to split string by whitespace or by a dot?". Semicolon is neither whitespace, nor dot.

Comment: @MarekLipka OP might said that as he was unaware of that there is #scan method. BTW what OP said,as per that #scan is still working.. The example you have given it is your assumption..I answers as per the question,not as per the assumptions although..

Comment: I did't know there is scan method. I will use it, but `Marek Lipka` was first and give the right answer for my question. Sorry Babai and falsetru